# Remove trailing slash with htaccess but preserve query string

Tags: string, slash, trailing

I am using following directives in my htaccess to remove trailing slashs from my uris to prevent duplicate content. However these directives also remove any query string, that might be present.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mydomain\com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I'd like to know how to remove a potential trailing slash from my URI, but also preserve query strings.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I mod\_rewrite and keep query strings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12873137/how-can-i-mod-rewrite-and-keep-query-strings)

Answer (score 1):

There's a `RewriteRule` option flag for that: [`QSA`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa).

> Appends any query string from the original request URL to any query string created in the rewrite target