# How can I mod_rewrite and keep query strings?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

I want to mod_rewrite a URL to another page, but then I also want any query strings added to be preserved.

```
RewriteEngine On

#enforce trailing slashes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost/siteroot/$1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^apps/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$ index.php&app=$1
```

So if a user visits `apps/app1/`, `index.php?app=app1` is shown.
However, I want to be able to preserve optional query strings, so that visiting `apps/app1/?variable=x` returns `index.php?app=app1&variable=x`.

What mod_rewrite rule/condition would make this happen?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You need to add the [`[QSA]` flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) ("query string append")

```
RewriteRule ^apps/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$ index.php&app=$1 [L,QSA]
```

For page 301 redirects with the `[R]` flag as opposed to internal rewrites like this one, the query string is automatically appended. However, you must force it with `[QSA]` for the internal rewrite.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise it was that simple.

Comment: +1 Agree with @DanielOakey.. I was trying to hack something with regex and it wasnt working..

Comment: To clarify, it's not about rewrites vs redirects.  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa says:

When the replacement URI contains a query string, the default behavior of RewriteRule is to discard the existing query string, and replace it with the newly generated one. Using the [QSA] flag causes the query strings to be combined.

Comment: Maybe you guys already know, but make sure to leave NO SPACE before `QSA`. That's gonna end up in a HTTP 500...