# Redirect url with parametes to new location using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to redirect `domain.com/folder1/nisanth.php?id=1` to `domain.com/folder2/nisanth.php?id=1`. How can i write my htaccess line? I tried using

```
Redirect 301 /folder1/nisanth.php?id=$1 /folder2/nisanth.php?id=$1
```

but no use.

Comment: Please share more details - if the id is always `1`, why not put that into the rule?

Comment: Also, does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12873137/how-can-i-mod-rewrite-and-keep-query-strings help?

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
Redirect 301 /folder1/nisanth.php?id=(.*) http://www.domain.com/folder2/nisanth.php?id=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help you out

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/folder1/nisanth.php?id=(.*)$ /folder2/nisanth.php?id=$1 [L,R=301]
```