# 301 redirect to new page keep query string

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I want to do a 301 redirect from `old_page.php` to `new_page.php` and keep all query strings if they exist.

so `old_page.php` would redirect to `new_page.php`

`old_page.php?test=1` would redirect to `new_page.php?test=1`

Here is what I have below, but it's a 404 error.

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^old_page.php(.*) new_page.php$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: And this was to hard for you? https://www.google.com/search?q=rewrite+keep+query+string

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I mod\_rewrite and keep query strings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12873137/how-can-i-mod-rewrite-and-keep-query-strings)

Comment: I saw that thread.  Still not working:

    RewriteRule (.*)/old_page.php(.*) $1/new_page.php$2 [R=301,QSA]

Comment: Where did the `(.*)/` in front come from all of a sudden, and what exactly are you hoping to match _after_ `old_page.php`?

Comment: Here is what I have now which is not working either:  RewriteRule ^old_page.php(.*) new_page.php$1 [R=301,QSA]

Comment: There will be no `$1`, since there is nothing behind `old_page.php` to match.

Comment: This worked:  Redirect 301 /old_page.php /new_page.php

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This worked:

```
Redirect 301 /old_page.php /new_page.php
```

Comment: Do you have any ideas how to do the same thing but also have a hard coded QS parameter on the second url like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23607633/transfer-a-querystring-between-2-domains-using-an-htaccess-301