# Redirection, but preserve the query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

its possible to create a redirection, but preserve the query string?

example, the original URL :

```
`http://example.com/listing/?search_query=anykeyw&tax_location=newyork&wpas=1`
```

redirect to page

```
 `http://example.com/new-york/?search_query=anykeyw`
```

preserve the `?search_query=anykeyw`, that contains keyword for ads and listings kewywords...

any suggestions?

Comment: Use the `QSA` flag in your rewrite and it will send them in the request.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12873137/how-can-i-mod-rewrite-and-keep-query-strings

Comment: yes i use the `QSA` but the location dinamically changes after a submit a search form... i think first i need get string from URL `tax_location=newyork` THEN redirect to new-york.php page... its that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this in your root `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} tax_location=newyork [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} search_query=([^&]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^listing/$ new-york/?search_query=%1 [NC,R,L]
```