# merge QUERY_STRING params with a regex matched param in htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a .htaccess file that is redirecting URLS like this:

```
RewriteRule    ^companies/([0-9]{1,20})/(.*)/?$    /php/company-profile.php?id=$1    [NC,L]
```

Which matches a URL 'companies/12345/company-name-safe' and grabbing the unique id for company-profile.php.

This works great. But I include a list of jobs by that company on the page, which has pagination & order_by functionality.

So I also need to capture any extra URL params and pass to the php file.

E.g for a url: companies/12345/company-name?page=2&order_by=date+DESC

I don't want to have to change my URL structure if possible, I always want page 1 to be a clean URL without '?id=12345' on the end.

How can I do this?

Comment: You only have to add `QSA` flag to your rule (after `L` for instance). This way, the query string will be appended. From your example `companies/12345/company-name?page=2&order_by=date+DESC` will be rewritten to `/php-profile.php?id=12345&page=2&order_by=date+DESC`

Comment: @JustinIurman this worked, thank you! Will accept as the official answer if you wanted to write again as an answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I mod\_rewrite and keep query strings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12873137/how-can-i-mod-rewrite-and-keep-query-strings)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only have to add a `QSA` flag to your rule

```
RewriteRule ^companies/([0-9]{1,20})/(.*)/?$ /php/company-profile.php?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

This way, the query string will be appended. From your example `companies/12345/company-name?page=2&order_by=date+DESC` will be rewritten to `/php-profile.php?id=12345&page=2&order_by=date+DESC`.

The solution above is only valid if query string parameters can have the same names in your rule. Otherwise, you can capture them separately with a `RewriteCond` on `%{QUERY_STRING}` and then append them manually in the rule, for instance:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=([^&]+)&order_by=([^&]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^companies/([0-9]{1,20})/(.*)/?$ /php/company-profile.php?id=$1&xxx_page=%1&xxx_order_by=%2 [NC,L]
```

Note that in this current case, you don't need `QSA` flag anymore