# Apache rewrite rule to forward complete URL to different port

Tags: apache

I have the following Apache rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:8002$1 [P,L,NC]
```

The intention is to forward all incoming URL's to local port 8002 where an [Express](http://expressjs.com/) app is listening for incoming requests. The issue is that this rule forwards the base URL but not the query string parameters.

For example, it when Apache sees http://example.com/test/, Express sees http://example.com/test/ but when Apache sees http://example.com/test/?a=b, Express still sees http://example.com/test/.

How do I pass along the query string to port 8002?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best solution, but you could do:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:8002$1?%{QUERY_STRING} [P,L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the correct way to do this is add the QSA flag as answered at https://stackoverflow.com/a/12873205/82135

So,

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:8002$1 [P,L,NC,QSA]
```

works now.